# Putting an odd row of a matrix in reverse order

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

The exercise consists of putting the odd rows of a matrix in reverse order. I am trying to make the matrix access another equal matrix and take the values ​​from there since modifying them in the matrix to be changed does not give the result I wanted

This is the code

```
public void  horizontalReverse()
    {
        int cont = 0;
        for (int i=1; i<matrix.length; i+=2) 
        {
            for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) 
            { 
                 int matrixHelper = matrix[i][j];
                 matrix [i][j] = matrix[i][(matrix.length -1 )-cont];
                 matrix[i][(matrix.length -1 )-cont] = matrixHelper;
                    
                 cont++;               
            }
            cont = 0;
        }
    }
```

When I print the matrix the values does not change and I have no idea why

Comment: Well, I have not looked into it, but what could be is that the inner loop causes the *n*th element from the left is swapped with the *n*th element from the right, but you are walking over the *whole* array, so the elements are swapped back to their original place – that would be my guess.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems.

- As mentioned in the comments you are replacing swapped values twice, resulting in the same array.
- And you are indexing the columns based on the row index.  This will only work for a square matrix.

Here is a demo using a `"ragged"` matrix

```
int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3},{1,2,3,4},{1,2},{1,2,3,4,5,6},{1,2,3},{1,2}};
horizontalReverse(matrix);
for (int[] row : matrix) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2]
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 1]
```

Note that I elmininated `cont` and just used `j` and I changed the inner loop to go to `mat[i].length/2`.

```
public static void  horizontalReverse(int[][] mat) {    
    for (int i=1; i<mat.length; i+=2) {
        for (int j=0; j<mat[i].length/2; j++) { 
             int matrixHelper = mat[i][j];
             mat [i][j] = mat[i][(mat[i].length -1 )-j];
             mat[i][(mat[i].length -1 )-j] = matrixHelper;
        }
    }
}
```

In the future, it may help to place print statements at various locations to print selected values.  This is a good way to see if the program is working the way you expect it to.  You may also want to consider using a debugger and set break points to inspect the variables as you step thru the program.  The latter can take some practice if you are not familiar with debuggers.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The exercise consists of putting the odd rows of a matrix in reverse order. ..."*

Here is an example.

```java
<T> void reverseOdd(T[][] a) {
    T t;
    int m, n, x = a.length, y, z;
    for (m = 1; m < x; m++) {
        if (m % 2 == 0) continue;
        for (n = 0, y = a[m].length, z = y / 2; n < z; n++) {
            t = a[m][n];
            a[m][n] = a[m][y - n - 1];
            a[m][y - n - 1] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

```
before
[3, 7, 3, 2, 6]
[5, 3, 4, 3, 0]
[9, 8, 5, 0, 2]
[7, 1, 7, 6, 6]
[6, 3, 8, 6, 4]

after
[3, 7, 3, 2, 6]
[0, 3, 4, 3, 5]
[9, 8, 5, 0, 2]
[6, 6, 7, 1, 7]
[6, 3, 8, 6, 4]
```